# program is showing error in PhotoImage to open images in tkinter saying no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.9, python-3.10

I was making in GUI for a vending machine where i was trying to add images into the button but while making the program there the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "e:\kanu\Coding Languages\VS code\4th semester\Data simulation lab\project 
    p2\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 8, in <module>
        img_chips = PhotoImage(file= "chps.jpg")
      File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init_``_.py", 
    line 4093, in __init__
        Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\kanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
    line 4038, in __init__
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "chps.jpg": no such file or directory
```

NOTE i have used every format i.e.

```
file = r'chps.jpg'
file = "chps.jpg"
file = r"chps.jpg"
```

This is the code that is showing the error

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    main = Tk()
    #Now we need to make a GUI for the vending machine
    
    
    chips_lb = Label(main, text="Chips")
    img_chips = PhotoImage(file= "chps.jpg")
    chips = Button(main, text ="Chips", image = img_chips).pack()
    
    
    
    mdangl_lb = Label(main, text="Mad Angles")
    img_mdangl = PhotoImage(file = "mdangls.jpg")
    mdangl = Button(main, text ="Mad Angles", image = img_mdangl).pack()
    
    
    
    chklet_lb = Label(main, text="Chocklet")
    img_chklet = PhotoImage(file = "chcklet.jpg")
    chklet = Button(main, text ="Chocklet", image = img_chklet).pack()
    
    
    enter code here
    coke_lb = Label(main, text="Coca Cola")
    img_coke = PhotoImage(file = "coke.jpg")
    coke = Button(main, text ="Coca Cola", image = img_coke).pack()
    
    
    
    bskt_lb = Label(main, text="Biscuit")
    img_bskt = PhotoImage(file = "buiscuit.jpg")
    bskt = Button(main, text ="Biscuit", image = img_bskt).pack()
    
    
    
    pepsi_lb = Label(main, text="Pepsi")
    img_pepsi = PhotoImage(file = "pepsi.png")
    pepsi = Button(main, text ="Pepsi", image = img_pepsi).pack()
    
    
    
    mainloop()
```

all the file name in this program are correct
[image as proof for the file name confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG7l1.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing and modifying the path?

Comment: Are you familiar with the differences between the current working directory and the directory where the script might be?

Answer (score -1):

To fix this error make sure that your file path directory is located in the location where your program was created or you may specify the file path directory.

```
pathlib import Path
print(Path('C:', '/', 'Users'))
```

Comment: i have also tried this

Comment: same error in the program

Comment: and it is in the same directory